# Calling the parameterized constructor in class composition

Tags: c++

Composition is kinda like inheritance but instead of inheriting the super-class, the super-class is a data member of the sub-class.

In such cases, how do you call the parameterized constructor of the super-class whenever an object of the sub-class is created (I know that we can't use the terms sub and super class here but it's just for clarity).

```
class A {
    int a;
public:
    A() {
        cout << "\nDefault constructor of A called.\n";
        a = 0;
    }
    A(int x) {
        cout << "\nParameterized constructor of A called.\n";
        a = x;
    }
    int getA() {
        return a;
    }
};

class B {
    A o;
    int b;
public:
    B() {
        cout << "\nDefault constructor of B called.\n";
        b = 0;
    }
    B(int x) {
        cout << "\nParameterized constructor of B called.\n";
        b = x;
    }
    int getB() {
        return b;
    }
}; 

class C {
    int c;
public:
    A o;
    C() {
        cout << "\nDefault constructor of C called.\n";
        c = 0;
    }
    C(int x) {
        cout << "\nParameterized constructor of C called.\n";
        c = x;
    }
    int getC() {
        return c;
    }
};
```

B and C are two different versions of composition. How to call the parameterized constructor of A in either of them. I mean, please modify the class definitions accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Using [member initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

```
class C
{
private:
    A a;
    int b;

public:
    C(int x) :
        a(x),  // <- Calls the `A` constructor with an argument
        b(x)   // <- Initializes the `b` member to the value of `x`
    { }
};
```

Comment: Ok, this was just a set-up for my follow up question. Why do we need to include the super-class initialization (both in composition and inheritance) in the initializer list and not inside the constructor of the sub-class?

Comment: @Pretorious Because that's how C++ is designed?

Answer (score 0):

```
B(int x) : o(x) {
    cout << "\nParameterized constructor of B called.\n";
    b = x;
}
```

Note the intialization of member variable o using the parameter passed into B's constructor.

Comment: Ok, this was just a set-up for my follow up question. Why do we need to include the super-class initialization (both in composition and inheritance) in the initializer list and not inside the constructor of the sub-class?

Comment: If it was just a set-up for a follow-up question, why not just ask the follow-up directly? In any case it's just how the language decides to do it - by the time a constructor starts executing, all members have already been constructed (either via the initializer list or by having their default constructors called). I think it is a sensible way to do it.